# Bound properties are always null

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have the following.NET Razor Page, whatever I try, none of the properties seem to bind on `POST` and they are all null.

When I look at the object posted it, all the properties are null.

Tag helpers are included

```
@page
@model AppointmentModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rendez-Vous";
    ViewBag.pTitle = "Rendez-Vous";
    ViewBag.pageTitle = "Accueil";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
...
                <form id="formSubmit" method="post">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formrow-firstname-input" class="form-label">Prénom</label>
                                <input asp-for="Input.FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="formrow-firstname-input" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" autocomplete="firstname" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formrow-lastname-input" class="form-label">Nom de Famille</label>
                                <input asp-for="Input.LastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="lastname" aria-required="true" placeholder="Entrez votre nom de Famille" disabled />
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formrow-specialite" class="form-label">Cliniques</label>
                                <select id="formrow-specialite" asp-for="Input.Clinic" asp-items="Model.Locations" class="form-select"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label>Date désirée du rendez-vous</label>
                                <div class="input-group" id="datepicker2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="dd M, yyyy"
                                           data-date-format="dd M, yyyy" data-date-container='#datepicker2' data-provide="datepicker"
                                           data-date-autoclose="true">

                                    <span class="input-group-text"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar"></i></span>
                                </div><!-- input-group -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formrow-periode" class="form-label">Période de la journée</label>
                                <select id="formrow-periode" class="form-select">
                                    <option>Matin</option>
                                    <option>Après-Midi</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formrow-email-input" class="form-label">Courriel</label>
                                <input asp-for="Input.Email" type="email" class="form-control" id="formrow-email-input" placeholder="Courriel" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="formrow-email-input" class="form-label">Raison de votre visite</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="formrow-email-input" placeholder="Riason de votre visite"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary w-md">Soumettre</button>
        ...
</div>
}
```

I tried creating a separate class, pretty much spent an hour debugging. I tried putting in the body, nothing works. I'm on .NET 7.

This is my class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
#nullable disable
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace CBQAdmin.Pages
{
    [Authorize]
    public class AppointmentModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CBQAdminIContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<CBQIdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<AppointmentModel> _logger;
     
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }
        
        public SelectList Locations { get; set; } 

        public AppointmentModel(
            UserManager<CBQIdentityUser> userManager,
            ILogger<AppointmentModel> logger,
            CBQAdminIContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _context = context;
        }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [DataType(DataType.Text)] 
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)] 
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Clinic { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string PolicyNumber { get; set; }
            
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string Reason { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Locations = new SelectList(_context.Clinics.OrderBy(n => n.Name).ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            Input = new InputModel();

            if (user != null)
            {
                Input.Email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.FirstName))
                {
                    Input.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.LastName))
                {
                    Input.LastName = user.LastName;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PolicyNumber))
                {
                    Input.PolicyNumber = user.PolicyNumber;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            InputModel input = new InputModel();

            await TryUpdateModelAsync<InputModel>(
                input, "input", i => i.FirstName, i => i.LastName, i => i.PolicyNumber, i => i.Clinic, i => i.Reason);                 

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (user != null)
                {
                    EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
                    await emailService.SendAppointmentRequest(Input);
                }
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers **does not support disabled property** to [submit with forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) by default:

> The difference between disabled and readonly is that read-only controls can still function and are still focusable, whereas disabled controls can not receive focus and are not submitted with the form and generally do not function as controls until they are enabled.

For your scenario, you can change `disabled` to `readonly`.

```
<input readonly asp-for="Input.FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" 
                id="formrow-firstname-input" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" 
   autocomplete="firstname" />
```

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn’t the other properties at least show up? Or does it screw the entire form?

Comment: Hi @DavidAbitbol, yes, I test your shared code, the `Clinic` can be posted to backend successfully. This property should show up in the backend. `PolicyNumber` and `Reason` property do not display such input in your view, so they would be null in the backend.

Comment: Wow, 14 straight hours of coding will make you miss that I never bounded those fields in my view. Thanks a million